# What do x, y, and z denote in mavros topic /mavros/imu/data_raw

Tags: imu, geometry-msgs, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am using mavros to read the signals from the APM2.5. However I am not sure what x, y, z denote.

For example, in angular_velocity, I think the signals should be pitch, roll, and yaw in rad. How do x, y, and z correspond to them. Also, in linear_acceleration, what is the coordinates for x, y, and z, and are they in meter? Many thanks.

```
$ rostopic type /mavros/imu/data_raw
sensor_msgs/Imu
$ rosmsg show sensor_msgs/Imu
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
  float64 w
float64[9] orientation_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular_velocity
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] angular_velocity_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear_acceleration
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] linear_acceleration_covariance
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220333/what-do-x,-y,-and-z-denote-in-mavros-topic-/mavros/imu/data_raw/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-11-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2015-11-03**:
Also, how can I know the frequency of the signals. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In IMU message, x,y and z values under `angular_velocity` correspond to roll rate, pitch rate and yaw rate respectively. Because, roll is rotation around x axis, pitch is around y and yaw is around z. Angles are represented as quaternion under `orientation`. They are not Euler angles directly. You should convert them from Quaternion to Euler angles. Check Wikipedia for description about Quaternions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation.

`linear_acceleration` values should be represented as m/s^2 unless otherwise stated. You should check **REP-103** (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) for dimension and coordinate standards in ROS.

For publish frequency of a topic you can use, `rostopic hz /mavros/imu/data_raw`

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2015-11-03**:
Hi @Akif, thanks for your answer. I am confused about the quaternion representation for angular_velocity. I mean if the angular_velocity are under quaternion, there should be four values, namely x, y, z, and w, similar to the representation of orientation. Any hints on it?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-03**:
Only `orientation` is represented as quaternion, angular velocity is not. Its message type is `geometry_msgs/Vector3` and consists of x, y and z only.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2015-11-03**:
Thx @Akif. That helps a lot.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2015-11-03**:
@Akif, BTW, what is the output of a APM2.5 connected GPS. Is it a global NED position or a local position? Many thanks.